# C++ rapidjson deserialise multiply nested vectors

Tags: c++, serialization, vector, nested, rapidjson

I'm using C++ rapidjson to deserialise nested vectors of coordinates describing multipolygons, (simple example below - each vector can potentially have several elements).

```
{"object_id":23673788,
 "shape":"{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",
           \"crs\": {\"type\":\"name\",
                     \"properties\":{\"name\":\"EPSG:28356\"}},
                      \"coordinates\":[[[[494676.366258227,6950458.99430531],[494669.765296885,6950450.7417945],[494652.958032304,6950446.48693143],[494655.629859572,6950450.35180843],[494668.438691086,6950467.23234078],[494674.324283898,6950468.73991576],[494676.366258227,6950458.99430531]]]]
           }"
}
```

Rather than iterating explicitly through the JSON vectors, I would like to emulate with C++, the more concise use of parameterized types as shown below using one of the popular C# JSON serialisation libraries:

```
var mpCoordinatesString = mpCoordinatesObject.ToString();
List<List<List<List<Double>>>> theWrapper;
try
{
    theWrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<List<List<double>>>>>(mpCoordinatesString);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Exception Caught deserialising coordinates {0}", mpCoordinatesString);
   break;
}
```

Any ideas or examples around?

Thanks

Mike Thomas